# Grouped Collection Select Alphabetical Order Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, grouped-collection-select

**I finally figured out how to implement Dynamic Select menus using [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised).**

**Everything works, But how does one organize the Cities in the Dropdown by Name....**

Below is all of the code I've written. (Please let me know if you need any further information)

New to rails please help :)

**VIEWS**

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@book, @rating]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :state_id, State.order(:name),  :id, :name, {:include_blank=> "Select a State"}, {:class=>'dropdown'} %>
  </div>


  ### I would like the order of the cities displayed in the drop down to be alphabetized 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :city_id, State.order(:name), :cities, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank=> "Select a City"}, {:class=>'dropdown'} %>
  </div>        

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**: In your `City` model, add a [default scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope) that directs cities to be returned in alphabetical order:

```
# app/models/city.rb
default_scope :order => 'cities.name ASC'
```

Collections of `City` objects will, by default, be returned in alphabetically by name.

**Option 2**: Define a [named scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) *in your `State` model* that returns cities in alphabetical order as an association on a `State` object:

```
# app/models/state.rb
scope :cities_by_name, -> { cities.order(name: :asc) } # Rails 4

scope :cities_by_name, cities.order("name ASC") # Rails 3
```

Then, pass your scoped query to your `grouped_collection` helper:

```
f.grouped_collection_select :city_id, State.order(:name), :cities_by_name, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank=> "Select a City"}, {:class=>'dropdown'}
```

Comment: May I ask which solution you implemented?

Comment: i tried both, and they both worked. but I implemented the first one. thanks again

Comment: The second one doesn't work anymore with Rails 4. Anybody know a workaround without making the scope a function?

Comment: In rails 3, for the scope example, this gives me -> undefined local variable or method `categories' for #<Class:0x007fddfa31de60>. I have a class that has_many :categories. and Category belongs_to :type, which is what I'm doing the grouped selection on. Not sure if anyone came across this

Answer (score 5):

With Rails 4 :

```
# app/models/city.rb
scope :ordered_name, -> { order(name: :asc) }

# app/models/state.rb
has_many :cities, -> { ordered_name }
```

Answer (score 3):

If using Rails 5.X, you can use `default_scope`, in which the syntax is slightly different than in @zeantsoi answer.

```
default_scope { order('cities.name ASC') }
```

Comment: Note:  rails 5 deprecated the `default_scope` syntax shown in older answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [default_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class) with ordering for `City` model?

Or creating a `State` scope like that:

```
scope :ordered_cities, ->{ cities.order(:name) }
```

and than changing your select to

```
f.grouped_collection_select :city_id, State.order(:name), :ordered_cities, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank=> "Select a City"}, {:class=>'dropdown'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others in this thread, I had issues getting this to work with scope. Instead I got this working in Rails 5 by adding another association to the State model:

`has_many :cities_by_name, -> { order(:name) }, class_name: 'City'`