# Custom ordering for query results from ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite

I recently switched my project to postgres and it is messing up my select forms in small but annoying manner.

I have 2 select fields,

```
<%= f.collection_select :state,  State.all, :value, :name, {include_blank: '- Select State -'} %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :area,  State.all, :areas, :name, :value, :name, {include_blank: '- Select Area -'} %>
```

The first select field contains a bunch of States. The second select field contains a bunch of Areas/Districts grouped(optgroup) by States.

Using "seeds.rb", I inserted all the relevant data. Everything was inserted in alphabetical order.
In SQLite3, the select results are all presented alphabetically.
However, when i swapped over to Postgrsql, my :area select is now presenting its options in reverse alphabetical order which is terrible for user experience.

I have also tested the following scenario with the following query in the rails console:

```
State.find("Texas").areas
```

SQLite3 results:

```
[Area A, Area B, Area C]
```

Postgres results:

```
[Area C, Area B, Area A]
```

Is there any way i can get the same results as SQLite3 with Postgres while still using it with my "f.group_collection_select"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the default order in the `has_many` relationship.

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas, -> { order("areas.name ASC") }
end
```

Comment: God sent! I was trying to use it but didnt really know the right syntax. The rails guide doesnt provide the syntax. Where can u find more detailed explanation for these things?
I was trying  -> { order "'name' ASC" } on the belongs_to association. :(

Comment: "Examples" section: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Answer (score 1):

use order clause on name or id whichever appropriate(I'd prefer name) with default scope for Area.

```
default_scope { order(:name :asc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining a scope in your Area model

See : [Grouped Collection Select Alphabetical Order Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754942/grouped-collection-select-alphabetical-order-rails)